# Comparing comma separated strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 string's

```
string1="fruit,animal,vehicle";
string2="plane,fruit,culture,animal";
```

So if i compare string1 and string2 it should say true since fruit,animal is present in the string in both the strings else 
false if nothing is present.

Comment: So it returns true if at least one item appears in both strings?

Comment: explain exactly what the desired behavior is

Comment: Yes i tried using array's but its very slow.

Comment: @user1184100 Post your code in your question.

Comment: Basically string1 is equal to string2 if there is a common element between both of them.

Answer (score 3):

Comparing every element in array 1 with every element in array 2 can be very slow, because the runtime increases quadratically.

How about this algorithm to find duplicates:

1. concatenate the two arrays  - constant runtime
2. sort() the resulting array - runtime depends on the algorithm used by the javascript engine but should usually be O(n log n)
3. iterate over it comparing each element to the precedessor  - O(n) runtime

Note that when there can be duplicates in the input strings themselves, these need to be removed beforehand using the same technique.

Answer (score 0):

```
function compare(string1, string2) {
    var arr1 = string1.split(",");
    var arr2 = string2.split(",");
    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
            if (arr1[i] === arr2[j]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Will work, but guaranteed to be slow on sufficiently long strings.

Comment: `arr1` and `arr2` are implicit globals.

Answer (score 0):

```
var string1="fruit,animal,vehicle",
string2="plane,fruit,culture,animal";
function compare(string1, string2){
     var s = string1.split(",");
     for(var k = 0 ;k < s.length; k++){
        if(string2.indexOf("," + s[k] + ",") )
        { 
          return true;
        }
     }
     return false;
}


compare(string1, string2);
```